# What are the informal uses of "voilà"?

Tags: prépositions, sens, interjections

In a literal sense, *voilà* means something like *There it is*.  *Voilà le monsieur qui parle anglais.* There's the man who speaks English.

On the other hand, *voilà* is sometimes used as an exclamation, perhaps like "Bingo," in English.

*Eh voilà, c'est une longue histoire* (from Un homme et une femme).

How is *voilà* used informally, and does it have any particular meaning in this regard?

Comment: I'm not sure that your second example really corresponds to the "Bingo!" meaning, I'd say it's something more like "And there you have it, it's a long story".

Comment: Agreed, it's more like "there". _"Voilà, tu vois, je te l'avais bien dit!"_ -> "There, you see, I told you so!". _"Voilà!"_ -> "There you go!"

Comment: I'm not sure if there's really a question here, since the answer is pretty much given in the question...

Comment: @Raphink: That may be the way it looks to a native speaker. But I'm a foreigner, see "voilà" quite a lot, and "sort of" know the answer, but that's not the same as actually knowing. And part of the question is, "are there any other common meanings that I may have missed. The references to "depuis" and "il y a" in an answer below were enlightening, at least to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this article:

*Voilà* can be an informal replacement for `depuis` or `il y a` when talking about how long something has been going on or how long ago something happened.

---

J'ai trouvé cet article:

*Voilà* peut être un remplacement utilisé à la place de `depuis` ou `il y a`, quand on parle  à propos de quelque chose qu'est en train de se passer, ou à propos de quelque chose que se a passé il y a beaucoup de temps.

> - *Voilà 20 minutes que je suis ici.*
>     I've been here for 20 minutes.
> - *Nous avons mangé voilà trois heures.*
>     We ate three hours ago.

Tu peux trouver plus de information [ici](http://french.about.com/od/vocabulary/a/voila.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Voilà can be used to introduce something/someone :

> Voilà un café.
>
> Voilà Johnny.

Or used to describe an instantaneous event happening in the present

> Voilà que le téléphone sonne
>
> Ah voilà!

Or to explain things that have explained/said previously:

> Voilà ce qu'il m'a dit hier.
>
> Voilà ce que nous avons décidé.